# How to read 3 lines each from a text file of multiple lines using getline() function in c++?

Tags: c++, getline

I'm trying to read 3 lines from the text file using the `getline()` function.

It was working fine when I was reading 2 lines, as I was able to differentiate by calculating if it's an odd or even line. But with 3 lines, it's not possible that way. So, is there any way to do this using the `getline()` function?

This is how the data looks in the text file:

[image]

I want to read it in a way that each set of 3 lines represents a separate node in the code. So, the 1st line of a node is the name of the contact, the 2nd line of a node is the contact group, and the 3rd line is the phone number. In that way, I have data for multiple nodes stored in a series.

```
void reopenCB() {
    bool isEmpty;
    ifstream myfile("contactbook.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open() & myfile.peek() != EOF) {
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(myfile, x)) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                if (head == NULL) {
                    Node *newer = new Node;
                    newer->name = x;

                    newer->next = NULL;
                    newer->prev == NULL;
                    head = newer;
                } else {
                    Node *newer = new Node;

                    newer->name = x;
                    newer->next = NULL;

                    Node *temp = head;
                    while (temp->next != NULL) {
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }
                    temp->next = newer;
                    newer->prev = temp;
                }
            } else if (i % 2 != 0) {
                Node *temp = head;
                if (temp->phone_number == 0) {
                    stringstream convert(x);
                    convert >> z;
                    temp->phone_number = z;
                } else {
                    Node *temp = head;
                    while (temp->next != NULL) {
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }

                    stringstream convert(x);
                    convert >> z;
                    temp->phone_number = z;

                }

            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "  File is Empty so Cannot open...Sorry" << endl;
    }
}
```

This was working fine when I'd read 2 lines, but now as I have 3 lines, it's not reading correct values.

**EDIT:**

Updated code, as suggested:

```
void reopenCB() {
    bool isEmpty;
    ifstream myfile("contactbook.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open() & myfile.peek() != EOF) {
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(myfile, x)) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                if (head == NULL) {
                    Node *newer = new Node;
                    newer->name = x;

                    newer->next = NULL;
                    newer->prev == NULL;
                    head = newer;
                } else {
                    Node *newer = new Node;

                    newer->name = x;
                    newer->next = NULL;

                    Node *temp = head;
                    while (temp->next != NULL) {
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }
                    temp->next = newer;
                    newer->prev = temp;
                }
            } else if (i % 3 == 1) {
                Node *temp = head;
                if (temp->group_name == "") {
                    temp->group_name = y;
                } else {
                    Node *temp = head;
                    while (temp->next != NULL) {
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }

                    temp->group_name = y;
                }
            } else if (i % 3 == 2) {
                Node *temp = head;
                if (temp->phone_number == 0) {
                    stringstream convert(x);
                    convert >> z;
                    temp->phone_number = z;
                } else {
                    Node *temp = head;
                    while (temp->next != NULL) {
                        temp = temp->next;
                    }

                    stringstream convert(x);
                    convert >> z;
                    temp->phone_number = z;

                }

            }

            i++;

        }

        myfile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "  File is Empty so Cannot open...Sorry" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain, why it was difficult to paste the text to the question, and why it was easier to make a screenshot, crop the image and paste the text as image to the question?

Comment: Please post your actual code. _Not_ an image of your code, but the code itself as text. And, ideally, the sample input and expected output as text as well. Also please give some details about what you're trying to do. I don't know what "working fine" meant for the old version, but I also don't know what the old version is.

Comment: I must be missing something. Put three getlines in a row (obviously that reads three lines). Then put that code in a loop, Loop until you've read the whole file.

Comment: It helps to post the code you have tried, that often makes it easier to see the real problem behind the question.

Comment: sorry for that...I've uploaded the code now

Comment: Assuming creating a linked list is part of the academic requirement, you probably want to remove the linked list logic from the input code putting the linked list in its own class and have a node class or struct. Also @john gave the obvious solution to the file reading problem. You are making it way more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to just read all three lines directly, inside a loop. Something like this:

```
std::string name1, name2, phone;
while (std::getline(myfile, name1) &&
       std::getline(myfile, name2) &&
       std::getline(myfile, phone))
{
    // Create a node and initialize it with all values
    // Add the node to your list
}
```

---

You probably don't need your own linked list either, unless it's part of your assignment or exercise. And if it is, then I recommend you separate the list from the nodes, and the nodes from the data it stores.

Basically create three different classes: `List` which handles the top-level list handling, like adding data to the list, iterating over the list, etc.; `Node` which is the node-structure itself; And `Data` which holds your data. Make `Node` have a `Data` member, and the `List` class functions to add nodes takes a `Data` argument. The `Node` class is used only internally in the `List` class.

Comment: I've to use nodes...it's part of the assignment..that's why..I can't go with this method

Comment: This method is perfectly compatible with nodes and rolling your own linked list. Just fill in the commented-out body of the loop with code that works with your own container. But the basic idea of "read in three lines at once, then create a node out of those three lines" is a major improvement over your current setup, where you have to walk the entire linked list from head to tail for most of your updates.

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer. Reading a file three lines at a time, and making a linked list are two different tasks. Each task should be solved separately. Programming is going to be very hard for you until you learn this lesson.

Comment: @FaseehHyder I agree. Your code is FAR too complicated for its own good.  It can be greatly simplified, eg: `Node **n = &head; Node *p = NULL; while (*n) { p = *n; n = &(p->next); } string contact, group, phone; while (getline(myfile, contact) && getline(myfile, group) && getline(myfile, phone)) { Node *newer = new Node; newer->name = contact; newer->group_name = group; istringstream(phone) >> newer->phone_number; newer->prev = p; newer->next = NULL; *n = p = newer; n = &(p->next); }`

Comment: thankx it worked....yupp this is way better

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `if (i % 2 == 0)` and `if (i % 2 != 0)` to:

`if (i % 3 == 0)`
`if (i % 3 == 1)`
`if (i % 3 == 2)`

But I would recommend rewriting this logic, and follow a more simple and readable solution (as in [@Someprogrammerdude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74278926/65863))

Comment: still having issue....now it shows in a different format...not working

Comment: I've updated the qs plz see again